# How to display the data of Salesforce lightning tree component in three columns

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to display users list in the for tree  hierarchy manner.
We are using lightning tree component, its displaying the data one column.

But we want to display data in three columns like below format.

> User1               ***   UserImage
>   User 1.1**             UserImage
>   User 1.2             **UserImage
>   User 1.2.1**         UserImage
>   User 1.2.2         **UserImage
>   User 1.2.3**         UserImage
>   User 1.3             **UserImage
>   User 2               ***   UserImage
>   User 3               ***   UserImage

**Here the problem is  "icon" variable we are storing user SmallPhotoUrl field of user object. while displaying its displaying as url not image.**

### Lightning component.

```
<div>
<lightning:tree items="{!v.items}" header="" onselect="{!c.handleSelect}" style="text-decoration:none;"/>
</div>
```

### Apex Controller.

```
List<User> userList;
User userObj = [SELECT ManagerId FROM User WHERE Id = :loggedInUserId];
if (userType == 'fromDashboard') {
    if (userObj.ManagerId != null) {
        userList = [Select Id, Name, SmallPhotoUrl, Score__c, Current_Month_Score__c, Current_Week_Score__c, Last_Updated_Date__c, ManagerId, UserRole.Name FROM User where(ManagerId = :userObj.ManagerId and IsActive = true) OR Id = :userId];
    }
    else {
        userList = [Select Id, Name, SmallPhotoUrl, Score__c, Current_Month_Score__c, Current_Week_Score__c, Last_Updated_Date__c, ManagerId, UserRole.Name FROM User where IsActive = true and Id = :userId];
    }
} else {
    userList = [Select Id, Name, SmallPhotoUrl, Score__c, Current_Month_Score__c, Current_Week_Score__c, Last_Updated_Date__c, ManagerId, UserRole.Name FROM User where ManagerId = :userId and IsActive = true];
}        
List<Items> finalUserList = new List<Items> ();
string cellAttributes = '';
String text = '';
String icon = '';
Id id;
Double point = 0;
String label = '';
String metatext = '';
String name = '';
String uId = '';
String managerId = '';
Boolean expanded = false;

List<Items> itemsList = new List<Items> { new Items(id, text, icon, label, metatext, point, name, userId, managerId, expanded, false, null, null) };          
itemsList.remove(0);

list<Items> TestItems=new list<items>();
String loggenInUserManagerId = userObj.ManagerId;
for (User user : userList) {            
    icon = user.SmallPhotoUrl;
    if (type == 'Monthly') {
        if (user.Current_Month_Score__c == null) {
            user.Current_Month_Score__c = 10;
        }
        label = user.Name + ' ' + user.Current_Month_Score__c + ' ' + System.Label.Points_Label+' '+icon;
        point = user.Current_Month_Score__c;
    } else if (type == 'Weekly') {
        if (user.Current_Week_Score__c == null) {
            user.Current_Week_Score__c = 5;
        }
        label = user.Name + ' ' + user.Current_Week_Score__c + ' ' + System.Label.Points_Label+' '+icon;
        point = user.Current_Week_Score__c;
    } else {
        if (user.Score__c == null) {
            user.Score__c = 100;
        }
        label = user.Name + ' ' + user.Score__c + ' ' + System.Label.Points_Label+' '+icon;
        system.debug('label'+label);
        system.debug('System.Label.Points_Label'+System.Label.Points_Label);
        point = user.Score__c;
    }
    id = user.Id;
    //icon = user.SmallPhotoUrl;
    // cellAttributes='<img src=""+user.SmallPhotoUrl>';
    metatext = user.UserRole.Name;
    name = user.Id;
    userId = user.Id;
    managerId = user.ManagerId;
    expanded = false;

    itemsList.add(new Items(id, text, icon, label, metatext, point, name, userId, managerId, expanded, false, null, null));
    itemsList.sort();
}

if (existingUsersJson != null) {
    //System.debug('existingUsersJson : ' + existingUsersJson);
    List<Items> fieldList = (List<Items>) JSON.deserialize(existingUsersJson, List<Items>.class);
    for (Items item : fieldList) {
        finalUserList.add(item);
    }
}

for (Items itemObj : itemsList) {
    List<Items> tempItemList = new List<Items> { new Items(null, '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', '', false, false, null, null) };
        itemObj.items = tempItemList;
    //itemObj.children=tempItemList;
    if (userType == 'fromDashboard') {
        if (loggenInUserManagerId != null && itemObj.managerId == loggenInUserManagerId && itemObj.name != null && itemObj.name != '') {
            if (itemObj.userId == loggedInUserId)
            {
                if (!finalUserList.contains(itemObj)) {
                    finalUserList.add(itemObj);
                }
            } else {
                if (!finalUserList.contains(itemObj)) {
                    itemObj.disabled = true;
                    finalUserList.add(itemObj);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (itemObj.userId == loggedInUserId)
        {
            if (!finalUserList.contains(itemObj)) {
                finalUserList.add(itemObj);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (itemObj.managerId != null && itemsList != null && itemsList != null) {
            finalUserList = getFinalUserList(itemObj.managerId, itemsList, finalUserList);
        }
    }
}
system.debug('finalUserList>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'+finalUserList);
return finalUserList;
```

Answer (score 1):

lightning-tree does not support showing image types. You would need to write your own component. Generally speaking, things not mentioned in the documentation cannot be done.

Comment: could you please suggest me the possible steps to achieve this